Getting error while trying to generate wtns file in ZKP
Actullay I was trying to generate a witness file in a zero knowledge project. Here is my circom code
pragma circom 2.0.0;

include "./node_modules/circomlib/circuits/poseidon.circom";

template PassportVerifier() {
    // Input: passport data (hashed)
    signal input passportHash;  // This will be a hashed value of passport data
    signal input secret;        // Some secret value to verify against
    signal output verified;     // Output verification result (True or False)

    // Hashing the secret
    component hasher = Poseidon(1);
    hasher.inputs[0] <== secret;

    // Create a constraint to ensure the hashes are equal
    passportHash === hasher.out;

    // Always output 1 if the constraint is satisfied
    verified <== 1;
}

// Instantiate the circuit template
component main { public [passportHash] } = PassportVerifier();

I get the r1cs , sym and wasm files successfully with the command circom passport.circom --r1cs --wasm --sym  command. But when I try to make the witness file with the command node passport_js/generate_witness.js passport_js/passport.wasm input.json passport_input.wtns I get error :
➜  passport_validator node passport_js/generate_witness.js passport_js/passport.wasm input.json passport_input.wtns 

/mnt/programming_projects/BlockChain/circom_Tests/passport_validator/passport_js/witness_calculator.js:166
                    throw new Error(err);
                          ^

Error: Error: Assert Failed.
Error in template PassportVerifier_70 line: 16

    at /mnt/programming_projects/BlockChain/circom_Tests/passport_validator/passport_js/witness_calculator.js:166:27
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WitnessCalculator._doCalculateWitness (/mnt/programming_projects/BlockChain/circom_Tests/passport_validator/passport_js/witness_calculator.js:141:14)
    at WitnessCalculator.calculateWitness (/mnt/programming_projects/BlockChain/circom_Tests/passport_validator/passport_js/witness_calculator.js:179:20)
    at /mnt/programming_projects/BlockChain/circom_Tests/passport_validator/passport_js/generate_witness.js:11:39

Node.js v22.11.0

This is my input.json file.
{
    "passportHash": "0x2b4f7b8428d5f4fd4f7c80a19c7636809a7a6d165cb90848fbbfbaf47e32e7de",
    "secret": "0xdeadbeef"
}

What am I doing wrong here ? Can anyone help me out ?
